# Compress set of mostly known bitstrings

Tags: data-compression

Let's say there is a *sender* sending *messages* with *commands* to a *recipient*.

1. The *sender* knows a set of *commands* but doesn't know anything about the recipient. A command is simply an opaque uniform random 128-bit string. E.g., the sender might know these commands and what they do:

   ```
   (1)  0x'BC04672BCEB7AEE08E555599F051F1CF'
   (2)  0x'E3D0AC4094435D3093B99CFA31746B93'
   (3)  0x'91014098C485DA109A39D52CDB611AD2'
   (4)  0x'00156B495D2C9F81AB783A277DF30044'
   (5)  0x'CADBBE207ABF184C95B33D707FB45552'
   ```
2. The sender then selects a subset of these commands and sends them in a *message* to the recipient. E.g.:

   ```
   (1)  0x'BC04672BCEB7AEE08E555599F051F1CF'
   (2)  0x'CADBBE207ABF184C95B33D707FB45552'
   (3)  0x'00156B495D2C9F81AB783A277DF30044'
   ```
3. The recipient also knows a set of commands and doesn't know anything about the sender. There is typically a large overlap of the set known by the sender and the set known by the recipient, but the recipient may know some commands that the sender doesn't know and vice versa. E.g., the recipient might know these commands:

   ```
   (1)  0x'D96F0AF780545565AD7721B1F9CD78C1'
   (2)  0x'00156B495D2C9F81AB783A277DF30044'
   (3)  0x'BC04672BCEB7AEE08E555599F051F1CF'
   (4)  0x'69E71BBB6393F1E1A5FAD6B50A960D6E'
   ```
4. For each command in the message that the recipient does know, it performs some action. The other commands it just ignores. E.g.:

   ```
   (1)  0x'BC04672BCEB7AEE08E555599F051F1CF' -> action
   (2)  0x'CADBBE207ABF184C95B33D707FB45552' -> ignore
   (3)  0x'00156B495D2C9F81AB783A277DF30044' -> action
   ```

I'd like to **compress the messages**. The main challenge is that each message must stand by itself and cannot (e.g.) build on any message exchanged in either direction before. There's little to no redundancy in a message that could be eliminated. However, since **most commands are known to both the sender and the recipient**, I'm wondering if there may be some way to exploit that fact to make the messages shorter.

Comment: Why are you sending long bistrings if a short "Command 5" or just "5" will do?

Comment: @vonbrand The bitstrings are part of a larger system that I have no control over. If I just send "Command 5", what bitstring is it referring to?

Answer (score 2):

One simple approach is to use what is known as a "priming text", which is a text that is representative of the text that you wish to compress (e.g. by containing a bunch of strings that you expect to find).

There are lots of ways to realise this, but we will take LZ77 as an example. LZ77 works by searching for common strings within a sliding window. You fix a window size (say, 64kb, which is small today, but this is for illustration purposes). At any point in the text, the compressor either encodes literal characters, or a reference to some string within the previous 64kb.

Normally, you start with an empty window, because there is no already-transmitted text to refer to. But there's no reason why this has to be the case. If, instead, you fill it with a text that is known to both the sender and receiver, then the compressor already has some strings that it can refer to.

The same idea works with many other compression schemes: With LZ78, you could prefill a dictionary with priming text, with a PPM-like method, you could prime the model, and so on. It's not obvious to me how you would incorporate a priming text with the Burrows-Wheeler transform, but someone may have done it.

Comment: This requires that both sender and recipient share exactly the same priming text, right?

Comment: Yes. Although if the communication channel is sufficiently reliable, you could use the message traffic so far as the priming text.